# How to access the texblocks in a listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a listbox which I can successfully update with the data but now I want to access two specific textblocks which I want to  collapse and make the other visible. here is my xaml:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="myPM_MListBox" Margin="-5,0,-5,0" SelectionChanged="myPMListBox_SelectionChanged">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="#FF009E49" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF505050">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" Text="Message Date" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Normal" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,5,0" Background="#FFEFEFEF" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF505050">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" x:Name="PMMessagePubDate" Text="{Binding shdMsgPublishTime}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0,5,0" Background="#FFEFEFEF" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="#FF505050">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" x:Name="PM_MLimitedBody" Text="{Binding shdMessageText}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF000000" FontWeight="Normal" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0,5,0" Background="#FFEFEFEF" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF505050">
          <TextBlock Margin="5,5,5,5" x:Name="PM_MFullBody" Text="Show more..." FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="right" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Blue" FontWeight="Normal" Tapped="ShowFullBody_Tap" />
        </Border>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to hide PM_MLimitedBody textblock and show the PM_MFullBody textblock for the ShowFullBody_Tap event handler I have. But seems like I can't access the Visibility properties of these textblok in my .cs file. is there a way for me to access these textblock's visibility property in my .cs file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sender of `ShowFullBody_Tap` will be the `TextBox` that defines that event. You can then use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(...)` to get the `Border` and then the `Grid` and then look at `Grid.Children` to find the other borders with their textboxes.